# dedicated jenkins server running docker containers for my web app using Jenkinsfile - error connection refuesd

Tags: docker, jenkins, codeception

I am running a dedicated Jenkins server and I am running Docker containers for my web app using Jenkinsfile. I have a problem with codeception when running tests on port 80 : the connection is refused. Also the same happens when I manually go to the `web_test` container and test a basic `wget http://web_test` :

```
  Resolving web_test (web_test)... 172.18.0.6
  Connecting to web_test (web_test)|172.18.0.6|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

I am running all of the Docker containers in the Jenkins file, in a dedicated network and all of the containers can talk with each other, but when I try and use the `web_test` container to run a basic web test, I am getting this connection refused error. Here is a portion of my Jenkinsfile:

```
docker.image('memcached:latest').withRun('--network jenkins-net -P --name memcached') {f ->

    docker.image('selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1').withRun('--network jenkins-net -P --name firefox') { e ->

    docker.image('selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.53.1').withRun('--network jenkins-net -P --name chrome') { d ->

    docker.image('vendwatchdocker_db_test:new').withRun('--volumes-from db_test2 --network jenkins-net -P --name db_test') { c ->
    docker.image('vendwatchdocker_db_test:new').inside() {
    /* Wait until psql service is up */
        sh 'hostname'
    }
    docker.image('vendwatchdocker_php').inside("--network jenkins-net -P --name web_test") {
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `http` protocol by default is using port `80`. In your `docker run` options your `web_test` using `-P` option. That means it will exposes port randomly. Try define the port: `docker.image('vendwatchdocker_php').inside("--network jenkins-net -p 80:80 --name web_test")`

Comment: Thanks, yes I have tried that also and still having the same issue.  I think it is a problem with my apache config.  I tried running it using nginx and i was able to access port.